# Vector Initialisation - C++ -- getting error while initialising using list

Tags: c++, vector, list-initialization

```
vector<int> arr3 = {3, 6, 9, 12, 15};
```

I'm trying to initialise the vector by above method and it is throwing the following error:

```
vectors.cpp:102:16: error: non-aggregate type 'vector<int>' cannot be initialized with an initializer list
    vector<int>arr3 = {3, 6, 9, 12, 15};
               ^      ~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

C++ version is 14.0.3
I've also tried to run command: `clang++ -std=c++ <filename>` and command equivalent to this but this is not working.

Initialisation if vector

Comment: It's `-std=<version>`, so for example `-std=c++11`. By the numbering I assume you use Apple clang, which is notorious for setting C++03 by default instead of any newer version.

Comment: Understand the difference between your compiler version and the C++ standard version.